# Python - get the full file path a function was called from?

Tags: python

Given a module `mymodule.py`; and in it

```
def foo():
    X = # file path where foo was called from
    print(X)
```

How would I do what's described in the comment? Ie, if in test.py I did

```
from mymodule import foo
foo()
```

And then ran `python3 test.py` in the terminal, it should print the full file path of `test.py`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`sys.argv[0]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) to get the *main file* 's name, then you could use [`os.path.realpath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) to get the full path of it:

```
import os
import sys

def foo():
    X = os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])
    print(X)
```

Demo:

```
kevin@Arch ~> python test.py 
/home/kevin/test.py
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear; what I meant is the function is import from `mymodule` to `test.py`, and I want `test.py`'s filepath, not `mymodule`'s

Comment: @JonathanStein: That's my bad, however, please check my edit :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.path.realpath` to get full path to curently executing file:

```
import os

def func():
  full_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
  print(full_path)

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
  func()
```