# Detect the path of the file from which the function is called

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two files

File 1

```
/main/files/folder/main_file.py

from common.funs import path_fun
main():
   print(path_fun())
```

File 2

```
/main/common/funs.py

path_fun():
   retun "path"
```

The path_fun() function in /main/common/funs.py should return /main/files/folder/

I don't want to pass the path as an argument. I want the function to automatically detect the path of the file from which the function is called..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - get the full file path a function was called from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367512/python-get-the-full-file-path-a-function-was-called-from)

Comment: every module has variable `__file__` with path to this module so you can check it instead of use `path_fun()` - `import common.funs` and `print(common.funs.__file__)`

Comment: If you want the function to get the path, just return `__file__` and make sure it's not a local variable you've set something to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) package for this:

```
import inspect

def someFunction():

    somePath = inspect.stack()[1][1]
    print(somePath)
```

Answer (score -1):

why don't you use os.getcwd() in main_file.py?

```
/main/files/folder/main_file.py

from common.funs import path_fun
import os
main():
   print(os.getcwd())
```